# How to calculate with SCSS variables from function

Tags: sass

I have a function which converts px to rem. For example:

```
height: rem-calc(14px); // makes height: 1rem;
```

Now I would like to calculate with it from variables. For example:

```
$switch-track-width: rem-calc(50px);
$switch-thumb-size: $switch-track-width / 2; // making it 25px or 1.7857rem in this case
```

That doesn't work so I tried something else:

```
$switch-thumb-size: ($switch-track-width / 2) + 0rem;
$switch-thumb-size: (#{$switch-track-width} / 2) + 0rem;
```

Both `$switch-thumb-size` examples aren't working either. Now this is dividing but I'm also unable to get `times (*)`, `plus (+)` and `minus (-)` working.

I'm also having a problem when calculating with 2 variables. For example:

```
$switch-track-height: rem-calc(14px);
$switch-track-width: rem-calc(50px);
$switch-thumb-right: $switch-track-height - $switch-track-width;
```

I prever to keep the function inside the variable instead of in the property like: `height: rem-calc($switch-track-height);`.

If someone could tell me how to calculate with SCSS variables on both examples that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: not even close to being the same question @DamjanPavlica

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I managed to find something that is some what working. For example:

```
$switch-thumb-size: rem-calc(10px);
$switch-track-height: rem-calc(20px);
$something: calc( ( #{$switch-thumb-size} - #{$switch-track-height} ) / 2 );
```

This results in:

```
calc( ( 0.71428rem - 1.4285rem ) / 2 )
```

But there are problems with it. First if you know that what you calculated should always be minus and you therefor add a `-` sign infront of the variable it will not work. Example:

```
height: - $something; // Doesn't work
```

The second problem I have with this method is that it creates a lot of redundant characters.

Because it actually puts: `height: calc( ( 0.71428rem - 1.4285rem ) / 2 )` in your css instead of: `height: -0.35684rem`

Comment: Actually `rem-calc` is redundant. It works fine without it

Answer (score 10):

It is actually possible to enter a formula that is compiled to a number:
(first example taken from https://sass-lang.com/guide)

```
article[role="main"] {
  float: left;
  width: 600px / 960px * 100%;
}
div {
  width: $icon_width + 10px * 2;
}
```

compiles to

```
article[role="main"] {
  float: left;
  width: 62.5%;
}
div {
  width: 60px;
}
```

This only works with compatible units. Otherwise go with someting like

```
height: calc( 100vh - #{$head_height} - #{$main_height});
```

Comment: `width: $icon_width + 10px * 2;` does not compile to `width: 60px;`. It actually compiles to `width: 40px+10px*2;`. Calculations only seem to work when there is no variable involved. So `width: 40px + 10px * 2;` does indeed calculate to `width: 60px` but as soon as a variable enters the calculation, it's not calculated anymore.