# SCSS/Sass: Using a calculated variable from one scss class as the base for another

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

**SHORT VERSION/CLARIFICATION**

The gist of my question would be, assuming each value was unique to it’s context, would it possible to use undefined variables in sass, similarly to an algebraic function.

```
[formula for height of “.page-wrapper” div]
a * 0.75 = b

[formula for height of nested/child “sticky-vert” div]
b * 4 = c

a=the base value
b=the calculated value of the parent element
c=the calculated value of the child element
```

…and so and so forth

Most of the @mixins and @extend functions I’ve seen in sass have to do w/ overriding or replacing a display value like **color** or **margin** but not actually using calculations to get a new value from an "undefined" variable.

**LONG VERSION**

I have an SCSS document and I'm trying to take the numeric value from one class to use as the base for another class. Basically, I'm trying to take the height calculated from the parent class (".page-wrapper") to use as the base variable for it's child (".sticky-vert"). Is this possible to do, solely w/ sass and without javascript modifiers?

For what it's worth the website itself is set to horizontal scroll (except for the 1 section, explained below) and all the ".page-wrapper" element is set to display:flex along w/ its children. I want the child element to have four times the height as it's parent to accommodate for 4 diff content items within that section.

**1. Here are the values set at the top of my scss doc:**

```
/*Base Variables*/
    $height: 100vh; // *the default value for height*
    $width: 100vw; // *the default value for width*
```

**2. These are the calculations for the parent container(s), using the $height value:**

```
.header {height: $height * 0.14} // *header is 14vh, remains static / never scrolls*
.page-wrapper {height: $height * 0.75} // *page-wrapper is 75vh. This is a div container between the header and footer for the main content, this is the only area of the page that moves*
.footer {height: $height * 0.11} // *footer is 11vh, remains static / never scrolls*
```

Imagine it like a hamburger style webpage with only the middle moving.

**3. This is the new value I want to calculate, without using JS modifiers or the actual numbers for flexibility:**

```
.sticky-vert {height: height of ".page-wrapper" * 4} // Technically, the formula would be 75vh * 4 = 300vh but...
```

I don't want to plug the actual numbers in, in case I change the values later on down the line and have to plug in the new numbers again. Also while `sticky-vert {height: $height * 0.75 * 4}` could work it still requires plugging in the then-assumed value of the parent's height (75vh).

HTML SAMPLE:

```
<header class="colors-1">header text, etc etc</header>
        <div class="page-wrapper dark">
            <section class="sec-1">THE PAGE SCROLLS HORIZONTALLY</section>
            <section class="sec-2">UP UNTIL YOU REACH THE NEXT SECTION</section>
            <section class="sec-3 sticky-vert">
                <div id="vert-1">WHICH THEN SCROLLS VERTICALLY, STARTING W/ THIS DIV</div>
                <div id="vert-2">THEN IT SCROLLS DOWN TO THIS ONE.</div>
            </section>
            <section class="sec-4">NOW ITS BACK HORIZONTAL</section>
            <section class="sec-5">AND FINISHES HERE.</section>
        </div>
<footer class="colors-1">footer text, etc, etc</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following correctly, you may not need to do all these calculations. Instead, would it be possible to add the height values for the header and footer regions, and have them set to `position: fixed;`, which would lock these elements in place which you could set with `top: 0;`, et.al. Then the page wrapper (for the moving content) could have margins or padding set (depending on how the main content moves around) to offset from the header and footer regions. This method could avoid a number of calculations, allowing freedom for focusing on the other areas.

Comment: Thanks for this but I should also clarify: it's less specific to this example and more of a general scss/sass question about using one variable to define another variable. I just added the html example for context purposes.

Comment: In that case, there is a related discussion here: [How to calculate with SCSS variables from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190922/how-to-calculate-with-scss-variables-from-function). From what it looks like, the output isn't the computed value, but instead a calculation—this can work, but it's up to the client browser to compute the end value instead.